# Unable to handle promise rejection with mongodb and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code, that basically skips the mongodb document entry stage if the incoming documents are already in the database. However this function causes an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` when trying to close the `db connection` immediately after the async is complete.

```
async dbInsertMany(asset, timeframe, stream){
    try{
        const [currentAssetModel, multiStream] = this._getMultiModel(asset, timeframe, stream);

        // Don't run the db stage if zero length stream received.
        if(!multiStream.length==0){
            // Refactor this into a try..catch..finally block.
            try{
                await currentAssetModel.insertMany(multiStream);
                console.log('<SUCCESS>');
            }catch(err){
                console.log('<ERROR>', err);
            }finally{
                console.log('__DBINSERTMANY:FINALLY__');
            };
        }else{
            // await sleep(1000);
            console.log('[WARNNING] No unique documents to add.');
        }
    }catch(err){
        throw new Error('Application failure has occurred!');
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

The functions that follow are below:

```
async function dbCycle(){
    try{
        let asset = new AssetDatabaseHandler();

        try{
            await asset.dbInsertMany('BTC/EUR', '5m', demoMultiExchangeStream)
            console.log('DB_INSERT_MANY: Finished.');
        }catch(error){
            console.log('DB_INSERT_MANY: [ERROR]', error);
        }
    }catch(failure){
        console.log('[SEVERE_FAILURE]', failure)
    }
};
```

and

```
(async () => {
    try{
        await dbConnection.dbConnect();
        console.log('Connected.');

        const result = await dbCycle();
        console.log('> Finished.');

    }catch(err){
        console.log('> Failed.', err);
    }finally{
        // dbConnection.dbDisconnect();
        console.log('Disconnected.');
    }
})();
```

Comment: You mean if `// dbConnection.dbDisconnect();` is uncommented, the unhandled rejection is thrown? Can you show the code for `dbDisconnect()` ?

Comment: Yes. But I have realised that the check I'm doing with the `AssetModel.exists()` returns a promise that I'm not waiting to resolve right now. So, probably some deeper issues exist. Maybe asked the question too early.

Comment: Ok - but still if `dbDisconnect` rejects that rejection would not be caught with your current code (as it happens in the `finally` block).

Comment: The problem is, the moment `dbDisconnect` executes, mongoose start to complain about the database connection being severed, but I don't have anything to do with the db at that stage, unless that `promised` `.exists()` is still resolving. I think that is the case.

Comment: Ok. Fixed it. Will post the answer below. It was exactly what I was suspecting. The `.exists()` is returning a `promise` naturally, and I was not waiting for it to fulfill and was closing the `db.connection`.

Answer (score 0):

The `.exists()` method is returning a promise, something  I have overlooked. Waiting for the promise to be resolved after the query is sent fixed the problem. Because I was not waiting for the promise and closing the server for cases where there was nothing new to be added to the db, the orphaned promises were causing the unhandled exception. Something like the code below, solved the problem:

```
async checkStates(stream, model){
    let state;
    let states = [];
    for(const item of stream){
        const date = new Date(millisecondsToTimestring(item[0]));
        const ISODate = date.toISOString();
        state = await model.exists({date: ISODate});
        states.push(state);
        // console.log(item, date, state);
    }
    return states;
}
```